# How to implement Google Analytics 4 in Laravel 10 Inertia Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, inertiajs

I am using laravel 10 built in reactjs and inertia with SSR on my new application.

I am trying to implement using this [react-ga4](https://github.com/codler/react-ga4) package.

The problem is I have no idea where to put initialize code in app root

```
ReactGA.initialize("your GA measurement id");
```

In `app.jsx` which comes from laravel looks like this

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

Where should I put the initialize and send code from react-ga4 package?

Comment: Here is a search from github [Link](https://github.com/search?q=ReactGA.initialize&type=code) You can check others how to implement. Hope it hleps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below to import the react-ga4 lib

...

```js
import ReactGA from 'react-ga4';



createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {
        // add this for the ga4 initialization
        ReactGA.initialize("your GA measurement id");

        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(<App {...props} />);
    },
```

...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).